# Rollup AOT error: "A module cannot import itself"

Tags: angularjs, angular2-aot, ng-lightning

I am using ng-lightning in my Angular project, when running AOT I get the following error, for one of the modules in ng-lightning

```
aot\node_modules\ng-lightning\popovers\popover.ngfactory.js (10:0)

        A module cannot import itself
    ..
    import * as i3 from './popover.ngfactory';
```

any idea how to overcome such an error?

Answer (score 4):

There is an [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17389) currently in angular 4.2 that causes this problem when compiling using rollup. I suggest either downgrading to angular 4.1 for now or wait for a patch.

Comment: what needs to be downgraded? This is weird, because I only have this issue with ng-lightning, not AOT in general

Comment: Angular itself. It affects other packages that depend on angular. See https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5081 and https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/ed73d4f3ac6b542bf5ea3eb73fbe91e2ceabcdb4. What version of angular are you using in your project?

Comment: I am using 4.2.2. So do you suggest to downgrade core?

Comment: Yes. I am experiencing the same issue using angular-material and downgrading to 4.1 until a fix is available worked for me.

Comment: will you share your package.json for the parts related to angular?

Comment: Please see the [example](https://github.com/Karasuni/angular-seed/tree/material) from the issue link in my previous comment. This repo experiences the exact same issue. When using [4.1.3](https://github.com/Karasuni/angular-seed/tree/material-4.1) I had no issues.

Comment: so we need to use ~4.1.3 instead of ^4.1.3 in order not to get 4.2

Comment: Yes - `^` will update `4.x.x` and `~` will update to any `4.1.x`. Usually `^` won't introduce breaking changes but this is a specific case of a breaking bug that has not been resolved yet.